# Reference for the Construction of Brownian Motion

Tags: reference-request, brownian-motion

A common method for constructing Brownian motion is referred to as the
Levy construction, the Levy-Ciesielski construction, the Ciesielski
construction and sometimes seems to be attributed to Wiener (1923). At
least in the book, Diffusions, Markov Processes and Martingales by
Rogers and Williams, I can find a reference for Ciesielski:

```
@article{Ciesielski61,
 author = {Z. Ciesielski},
 title = {Holder condition for realization of {G}aussian processes},
 journal = tams,
 volume={99},
 year = 1961,
 pages={403--413}
}
```

Can someone point me at the references for Levy and Wiener? Or perhaps
even better there is an article with a short history of the
construction of Brownian motion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The monograph *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by René Schilling & Lothar Partzsch contains (proofs of) the following constructions of Brownian motion:

- Lévy-Cieselski construction
- Wiener's construction
- Lévy's construction
- construction via orthogonal series
- (sketch of) Donsker's construction
- construction via Kolmogorov's existence theorem

Comment: Thanks very much - it looks a good book - sadly it will require payment.

Comment: @DominicSteinitz True enough, but compared with other (mathematics) books it is rather affordable. Perhaps there is a library where you can borrow it?

Answer (score 0):

The reference for Lévy is:

Lévy, M. Paul. “Le Mouvement Brownien Plan.” American Journal of Mathematics, vol. 62, no. 1, 1940, pp. 487–550. JSTOR, [www.jstor.org/stable/2371467](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371467). Accessed 24 Nov. 2020.