# Looking further at sum of Gaussian random variables will look like a Brownian motion

Tags: normal-distribution, brownian-motion

In this video [CLICK HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a66tfLdr6oY&t=3065s), the professor says `at 51:19` that if we add `n` Gaussian random variables and we see that sum further and further from our eyes, the result will look like a Brownian motion.

I do not not really understand what he means. I know that adding Gaussian random variables will be Gaussian and even if they are not originally Gaussian, the result will be Gaussian if `n` is high enough (by the central limit theorem). So I can not see any explanation on the internet that says that if we look further at the sum of Gaussian random variables, the result would look like a Brownian motion. Is there any interesting link that you can share with me concerning this fact?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: do you have James Hamilton's text "Time Series Analysis" ? He has a section ( It's the chapter which discusses unit roots )  where he shows something very similar ( can't recall if it's exactly what you want ) to what you describe.

Comment: I wrote below a long time ago. It's okay and somewhat related but I would get my hands on hamilton's text for a nice explanation.  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/random-walk-with-normal-increments-and-n-time-periods-why-is-the-increment-sqr/43224#43224

Comment: @markleeds Thank you for your help and comments!

Comment: your welcome. I hope that it helped some. if you're in school, hamilton's text might be in the math library ?

Comment: @markleeds I am not sure but I will ask our library to see if it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "add" (or "sum") is being used imprecisely here. You can construct an approximation to a Brownian motion by starting with $n$ independent standard Gaussian variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. Define the *partial sums*
$$
S_0:=0,\quad S_1:=X_1, \quad S_2:=X_1+X_2,\ \ldots,\  S_k:=\sum_{i=1}^kX_i,\ \ldots,\  S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i.
$$
Then plot $S_k$ versus $k$ in the plane, and connect the dots. This creates a continuous function. Under suitable scaling of the $x$ and $y$ axes, this function converges to a Brownian motion as $n\to\infty$. "Looking at this from farther and farther" is an informal way of saying "under suitable scaling".

There are many ways to construct Brownian motion: see [Reference for the Construction of Brownian Motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/936168/215011). Donsker's Theorem, mentioned in the video, justifies the construction of Brownian Motion as the [scaled limit of a random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275121/215011).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Do you have a specific reference of what you wrote and which is available online?

Comment: @Christina  The construction described above is a special case of what's discussed in the second link. Note that we are starting with $n$ iid random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. The formula $S_t = S_{[t]}+ (t-[t])(S_{[t]+1}- S_{[t]})$ seen in the linked post is simply connecting the dots of the partial sums to create a continuous sample path. And the new process $S^*_n(t)= \frac{S_{nt}}{n}$ is exactly the scaling that's needed to obtain Brownian motion as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: (Actually the scaling should be $S_{nt}/\sqrt n$.) For another reference, the [Wikipedia page for Donsker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) discusses a related construction, where the sample paths are piecewise constant instead of continuous.

Comment: Great! thank you a lot for these information. Your help is so much appreciated.